# SQL - Categorize Transactions by group

Tags: sql, databricks-sql

I want to add a column to my table called Group, based on the on the column Category. I have already filtered the table so its already dog/puppy or multi. Does anyone one know how to do that?

| Trans_ID | Category | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dog | Multi |
| 1 | Puppy | Multi |
| 1 | Dog | Multi |
| 1 | Cat | Multi |
| 2 | Dog | Only Dog |
| 2 | Puppy | Only Dog |
| 3 | Dog | Only Dog |
| 3 | Dog | Only Dog |

I tried Case statements and I am writing this in databricks sql.

Comment: Sorry I fixed it. I want to know how to add the far right column named Group

Comment: What you're after (examining a set of rows _without_ aggregating it in a `GROUP BY`) can be considered a form of Relational Division: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/learn/high-performance-relational-division-in-sql-server/ - but you can probably do this with only window functions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Databricks, so I'm writing this blind. You might find some mistakes.

However I think the key is that your logic seems to need an intermediate group, which I'll call "Mapping" in this SQL to avoid confusion.

```
WITH cte_mapped AS
(
       SELECT *,
              CASE
                     WHEN category IN('Dog',
                                      'Puppy') THEN 'Dog'
                     WHEN category IN('Cat',
                                      'Kitten') THEN 'Cat'
                     ELSE 'Unmapped'
              END AS category_mapping
       FROM   tbl 
), cte_grouped AS
(
       SELECT *,
              CASE
                     WHEN SIZE(COLLECT_SET(category_mapping) OVER(partition BY trans_id) > 1 THEN 'Multi'
                     WHEN SIZE(COLLECT_SET(category_mapping) OVER(partition BY trans_id) = 1 THEN 'Only'
                     ELSE NULL
              END AS category_type
       FROM   cte_mapped 
)
select trans_id,
       category,
       CASE
              WHEN category_type = 'Multi' THEN category_type
              WHEN category_type = 'Only' THEN concat(category_type, ' ', category_mapping)
              ELSE NULL
       END AS GROUP
FROM   cte_mapped
```

The `SIZE(COLLECT_SET())` is essentially a window function similar to `COUNT(DISTINCT())` in most other databases.